# File system in Toit

Tags: file, directory, filesystems, toit

Judging by the **lib_v1.0.2** library, access to the *file system* is implemented in **Toit**. May be can give some simple examples, which would include:

1. Create a file,
2. Writing data to file,
3. Reading data from a file,
4. Deleting a file,
5. Is there support for folders, and if so, what is the nesting level and how to get a list of files in the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2022-12-20: the `host` package's filesystem functionality (`host.file` and `host.directory`) is now supported for sdcards.

The filesystem libraries are not supported on ESP32 devices. They were implemented for host machines (like Linux), but that version isn't released.

The libraries will likely move soon and then not be accessible anymore.

If you want to store data on the device, maybe the device flashstore works for you:

```
import device

main:
  store := device.FlashStore
  store.set "key" "data"
```

Comment: This really works, can to save multiple items of data. Key is string, data is any object. Reading data: data: = store.get "key".

Comment: I believe the data is serialized using the `serialize` library https://libs.toit.io/serialization/library-summary#serialize(1%2C0%2C0%2C) . This means it can't be of any type.

Comment: A small bug related to saving the map-object in the flash store. If you use string as a key, then there are no problems, but if int, then crash occurs.